# How to lock a part of method from another threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

How can i lock a part of method in c# from another threads?
I mean if one of threads was here, then exit...
For example:

```
if(threads[0].WasHere)
{
   return;
}
```

Comment: see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

an effective way is with an interlocked exchange; by setting some token field to a non-default value during the work, the other threads can check this and exit. For example:

```
private int hazWorker; // = 0 - put this at the scope you want to protect
```

then:

```
// means: atomically set hazWorker to 1, but only if the old value was 0, and
// tell me what the old value was (and compare that result to 0)
if(Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref hazWorker, 1, 0) != 0) {
    return; // someone else has the conch
}
try {
    // your work here
} finally {
    Interlocked.Exchange(ref hazWorker, 0); // set it back to default   
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Monitor.TryEnter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.tryenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this purpose.

```
if(!Monitor.TryEnter(someLock))
{
   return;
}
try
{
    //Critical region
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(someLock);
}
```

Or more reliable way to fight with *Rude Thread aborts* (suggested by marc in comments)

```
bool lockTaken = false;
try
{
    Monitor.TryEnter(someLock, ref lockTaken);
    if (lockTaken)
    {
        //Critical region
    }
}
finally
{
    if(lockTaken) Monitor.Exit(someLock);
}
```

Note that this doesn't checks for `threads[0]` still working, rather it checks whether any other thread is in *Critical region*. If so, it exits the method.

Comment: In recent versions of .NET, the `ref bool` approach is much preferred (see http://pastie.org/9788159), but frankly you don't need `lock` if all you want to do is have a single caller in a block

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes you're right I know that's reliable way to go. But without and IDE this method was convenient for me to type. Yes I saw your answer is using `Interlocked` approach, I feel that's very low level. It's not that locks are expensive.

Comment: to my mind it isn't about whether one is more "low level" - it is simply about what features we are using. `Monitor` has a lot of features: blocking, queuing, pulsing, re-entrancy, etc etc etc - **none of which we need here**; all we actually want is a "is this already in use" flag - we can do that with a basic field, as long as we use atomic (interlocked) swaps

Answer (score 2):

You can use a bool value - assign it "false" on default, and then the first of the threads sets it to "true". And then the piece of code could look like this:

```
if (!alreadyExecuted)
{
    // ...
    alreadyExecuted = true;
}
```

I would also put the code in a lock to make sure only one thread executes it at time (to deal with any possible race conditions), like below.

The lockVariable is a locker variable and it can be of any reference type, ex. object lockVariable = new object();

```
lock (lockVariable)
{
    if (!alreadyExecuted)
    {
        // ...
        alreadyExecuted = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also check for `aleardyExecuted` before the lock to avoid the locking cost in most cases. This technique is called "double checked locking" and is a common design pattern.

Comment: this not works fine, beacause when many threads tries to check "alreadyExecuted" variable this could be false and many threads goes into "if" block (Sorry for my english,thanks for answer!)

Comment: @Etienne is right actually, the additional check would improve performance, but the improvement would not be significant in this case probably. The performance improvement would depend on how many threads are running.

Comment: @CVVVLAD The idea is to check before AND after the lock. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

Comment: @EtienneMaheu yes,thanks i'm understood. Your method works nice. You was right and helpfull.